# Can't retrieve PID from `siginfo_t` on Linux using code that worked on Solaris

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, pid

I need to retrieve the PID of a child process from a `siginfo_t` structure.   This code works on Solaris:

```
siginfo_t *info; 
//
// siginfo is initialized with proper data here
//
pid = info->__data.__proc.__pid;
```

But when I tried to port my code to Linux, I got a compile error:

```
error: ‘siginfo_t’ has no member named ‘__data’
pid = info->__data.__proc.__pid;
```

This is the definition of `siginfo_t` on Solaris (from `signal.h`):

```
typedef struct {
    int             si_signo;
    int             si_code;
    int             si_errno;
    union {
        int             __pad[7];
        struct {
            pid_t           __pid;
            union {
                struct {
                    uid_t           __uid;
                    union sigval    __value;
                } __kill;     /* si_code <= 0 SI_FROMUSER */
                struct {
                    _CSTD clock_t   __utime;
                    int             __status; /* CLD_EXITED status, else signo */
                    _CSTD clock_t   __stime;
                } __chld; /* si_signo=SIGCHLD si_code=CLD_* */
            } __pdata;
        } __proc;
        struct {
            int             __fltno;
            void            *__fltip;   
            void            *__addr;    
            int             __bdslot;
        } __fault;                /* si_signo=SIGSEGV,ILL,FPE,TRAP,BUS */
    } __data;
} siginfo_t;
```

However, Linux `signal.h` has a completely different definition.  I don't understand how to write code that uses `siginfo_t` but works on both Linux and Solaris, please explain.

Comment: Names starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation. That alone should be an indicator not to touch those fields from your application.

Answer (score 4):

[The official specification of `siginfo_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) (you'll have to search for "siginfo_t", there are no fragment anchors, sorry) does not show *any* of the structure you quoted.  It is an internal implementation detail that you are not supposed to use directly.

(As a general rule of thumb, you are not supposed to make direct use of *anything* in a system header whose name begins with two underscores.)

Change your code to read

```
pid = info->si_pid;
```

and it will work correctly on both Solaris and Linux.  If you don't already have it, it would also be a good idea to add either

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

or

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
```

to the very top of each source file (it needs to come before all the `#include`s or it won't work) (pick one or the other, not both, depending on whether you need [XSI](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04) features).  Current versions of Solaris and Linux default to (approximately) this mode, but activating it explicitly can prevent surprises especially with older systems.

There are other names beginning with `si_` for all of the other useful fields in `siginfo_t`; the specification I linked to lists the universally available ones.  If you need to use fields that are OS-specific, look in the same header where you found `siginfo_t` for `#define`s of the form

```
#define si_pid    __data.__proc.__pid
```

and use the `si_` name.

Comment: thanks, will try. the info i picked up is from http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref%2Ftopic%2Fs%2Fsiginfo_t.html

Comment: Oh ghod, that documentation is just terrible.  Don't trust it for anything.

Comment: @girishs: Don't trust that site for anything other than what QNX has produced! Anyway, you also want to `#define POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before `#include <signal.h>`, to ensure `siginfo_t` etc. is provided in the GNU C library (and variants); this macro tells the C library (headers) to expose POSIX.1 functionality (up to POSIX.1-2008) which standardized this stuff as described in the page zwol linked to.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Typo: `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, with a leading underscore, and it needs to appear before _all_ system headers, not just signal.h.  That mode _should_ be on by default in current versions of glibc, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.